# Custom Reactjs Checkbox component needs dynamic colors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have created a react checkbox component I am struggling to make it so that I can call different background colors to the box once it checked. I want to be able to have a primary, secondary and info attributes.

I just don't know how to add this functionality to the checkbox component. I want different colors, types and size for the checkbox I would like to change background colors based on what type checkbox it is - so if primary = blue, success = green and so on.

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true,

    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }


  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });

  }


  render() {
    return ( 
     <div className="checkbox" onClick={this.onChange}>
      <div className="checkbox-box"> {
        this.state.checked &&
        <span className="checkbox-box-mark">
        <svg 
          viewBox = "0 0 64 64"
          xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
        <path 
          d="M21.33,57.82,0,36.53l5.87-5.87L21.33,46.09,58.13,9.36,64,15.23,21.33,57.82"/>
        </svg>
        </span>
      } 
      </div>  
      <div className="checkbox-label">checkbox</div> 
      </div>   
    );
  }
}
export default Checkbox
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is to set up a styles object in your `Checkbox` component to define `primary` and `success`, and `info` styles and add a `style` attribute to the parent `div` that updates its style based on the type (passed in through props) when the box is checked.

So there are three key things:

1) We pass in a `type` property to the component. In the component we assign that value to a new type property in state.

2) We set up a styles object that contains the background colours for each different checkbox type

3) We assign a colour object from the styles object if `checked` is true.

Let's break down how that works:

```
style={checked ? { width: '50px', ...styles[type] } : { width: '50px' }}
```

The `style` attribute accepts an object. In the case where `checked` is false we want to return an object that defines the width, but if `checked` is true we want to return an object with the width definition *and* the colour definition from styles. In the above line I've used a [ternary operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that translates as:

> if (checked) use the *combined* width object and `styles[type]` object (else) just use the object with the width definition`.

```js
const { Component } = React;

// App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Checkbox type="primary" />
      <Checkbox type="success" />
      <Checkbox type="info" />
    </div>
  );
}

// Checkbox.js


// Style definitions
const styles = {
  primary: { backgroundColor: 'blue' },
  success: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
  info: { backgroundColor: 'cyan' }
}

class Checkbox extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set a new type property in state and assign the
    // props value of type to it
    this.state = { type: props.type, checked: false };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
  }

  render() {
  
    // Destructure the type and checked properties from state
    const { type, checked } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div className="checkbox" onClick={this.onChange}>
        {/* If the box is checked set a width of 50px and apply the styles for that type */}
        {/* Otherwise just set a width of 50px */}
        <div
          className="checkbox-box"
          style={checked ? { width: '50px', ...styles[type] } : { width: '50px' }}
        >
          <span className="checkbox-box-mark" >
            <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M21.33,57.82,0,36.53l5.87-5.87L21.33,46.09,58.13,9.36,64,15.23,21.33,57.82"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Further reading

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the help - I am quite new to this and its way over my head at the moment. I see it working but dont understand why its working and how I can make mine work like yours.

Comment: @Fulano, I've added some additional commentary to the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite easy:
1. define your component type ("primary", etc) as a component state property
2. Remember to call setState when you want to change this property.
3. render all other dependent properties in a render method using conditional rendering:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

If still not clear, I let me know :)

Comment: Hi Denis, Thanks for the suggestion. I don't get the SetState - I keep on banging my head agains the wall.

Comment: Hi  Fulano, you can check how it works here: https://codepen.io/luvram/pen/MyKvOE (result is in the lower window part)

Comment: And here how you should set css properties: create classes with set of properties (background color, size, etc, and then set corresponding class): https://upmostly.com/tutorials/changing-the-background-color-in-react

Comment: Hi Denis, I get what the setState is doing there but how can I call my component like this: <Checkbox type='primary' > </Checkbox> The type primary here would be a className and that class will be blue and red if I call "warning" and so on. I think a need a function for that but dont know where to put it or the logic for it.